# Node Error, module compiled against different Node.js version, but my installed version matches the requirement

Tags: node.js, npm, bots, discord, better-sqlite3

Getting an error saying that the module I'm trying to load was compiled with NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83, not N_M_V 72 which is what it needs, but I have 72 installed (pls see pic for full text of error).

I know the bot is functional bc I was hosting it with no issues on Heroku for a week before I decided to shift to a vps/vultr. Got all my files transferred to the remote server, get npm and node installed as well as all the various modules that my dependencies call for. I forced install of the version of node/npm that the code was developed using and installed the modules after that. I've tried rebuilding and completely uninstalling both node/npm and the modules and am still getting this error. [I cant copy the error code and I dont want to have a typo but its here, sorry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx1Pf.png)

[Edit: npm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnUJ5.png)

Comment: did you try the instruction of `npm rebuild`? and can you post the `npm install` logs? Because the native module should be picked or build during install

Comment: Yes, I tried both removing and reinstalling npm and following the rebuild instructions I had seen on other similar questions posted

Comment: Inside your project folder can you delete package-lock.json and node_modules folder and then run command npm install

Comment: Yes, I have tried completely removing the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file, same result as above

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: The vultr console (where I have to run the code for the remote host) does not allow copy/paste and I didn't want to make a typo that would lead to the wrong conclusion about my problem. I understand that text is better for searching/better practice for accessibility in general and would def rather use text.

Comment: idk what the difference is, but I uninstalled and reinstalled everything again and (after once again having to force the correct versions) it's working now.